# Google Sheets, Conditional Formating not applying to all rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is a fairly basic conditional format rules in Google Sheets.

It is finding the highest number for each row. It skips row 27 for some reason, I know how to do these, I have done it many times below and the rest of the spreadsheet works.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, as well as the current format rule you are using?

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=B25=MAX($B25:$K25)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, I am new here but this place really lives up to it's reputation.

I wish you great blessing!